# Can you create gradients that fade to opacity using CSS or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, opacity, gradient

WebKit has introduced the ability to create CSS gradients. For example, with the following code:

```
-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fff), to(#000));
```

However, is it possible to have an opacity gradient using CSS? I want the gradient to be a single color on one side, and fade to zero opacity on the other.

Cross-browser compatibility isn't important; I just need it to work in Google Chrome.

Is there some way to do this using CSS? If not, can something similar be done using JavaScript (not jQuery)?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes

for the colors, use rgba(x, y, z, o) where o is the opacity

should work

e.g.

```
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)));
```

**Edit:**
For the final value (opacity) 1 is opaque & 0 is transparent

Comment: You probably meant (255, 255, 255, 1) for the first value.

Comment: code doesnt actually work, appears to be missing commas and brackets

Answer (score 16):

Yup, `rgba(red, green, blue, alpha)` is what you should use http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#rgba-color, example (Try it out on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ZbW5/2/)):

```
/* Webkit */
background: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left bottom,
    left top,
    color-stop(1, rgba(0,0,0,0.0)), /* Top */
    color-stop(0, rgba(0,0,0,1.0)) /* Bottom */
);

/* Gecko */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(
    center bottom,
    rgba(0,0,0,1.0) 0%, /* Bottom */
    rgba(0,0,0,0.0) 100% /* Top */
);
```

Comment: Create an svg gradient and base64 encode it  `background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyPC9saW5l...3N2Zz4g');`

Answer (score 2):

not tested, but this should work (in FF this works (with a different syntax) - i'm not sure if safari/webkit knows rgba):

```
-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(255,255,255,1)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0)));
```

Comment: I might've misunderstood something, but why would you expect a `-webkit` vendor-prefixed property to work in Firefox? (`-webkit` applies to Chrome and Safari, and one or two others; `-moz` is for Firefox; `-o` is Opera; `-ms` is, apparently, IE...)

Comment: thanks for the hint, i've edited that... i just forgot to write some text (thats what happens if you drink alcohol while sufing on stackoverflow on sunday evening -.-')